# Icon position switching left right automatically on removing position:absolute

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using the Vuetify tooltip feature.

The span message appears like this as below(image 1). Here in the CSS I checked .tooltip__content {
      position: absolute; }. So I changed it relative as .tooltip__content {position: relative;}. But now the issue I am facing is the icon keeps switching positions as in image 2 on hover over the icon. What did I do wrong?

[image: Image1]

[image: image2]

```
                <v-container fluid>
                  <v-layout row wrap>
                    <v-flex xs11 md6 class="add-col-padding-right">
                        <v-text-field 
                                label='Demo'
                                v-model='dummy.info'
                                >
                        </v-text-field>
                    </v-flex>
                    <v-flex xs1 md6 class="add-col-padding-left">
                      <v-tooltip attach>
                        <a href='javascript:void(0);' slot="activator">
                          <i class="material-icons icon-black">
                            message
                          </i>
                        </a>
                        <span>Please enter the user information correctly.</span>
                      </v-tooltip>
                    </v-flex>                    
                  </v-layout>
                </v-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably nothing wrong, Vue likely just has a CSS rule for on hover. Try adding your own to override it:

```
v-tooltip:hover {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I added this. but no difference. span text still appears the same

Comment: If you use Chrome or Firefox browsers check the element and force the :hover via the dev tools. Their CSS rule is probably more specific than yours and therefore gets priority. You could also try changing `relative` to `relative!important`.

Comment: Then it causes the same problem as in image 2. Icon keeps on moving when I hover over the icon.

Comment: It appears to wrap because of the width of the tooltip. Can you set a width or max-width for the v-tooltip:hover?

Comment: Can you suggest me how to do that?